# Need to access special frames in the array

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In my game I have a dialogue screen and image panel, where I want to display [3-frames animation](https://twitter.com/dimaCyberpunk/status/754932275645558784) for each character. I do it with this script:

```
public Texture[] frames;                // array of textures
public float framesPerSecond = 2.0f;    // delay between frames
RawImage image = null;

void Start()
{
    image = gameObject.GetComponent<RawImage>();
}

void Update()
{
    int index = (int)(Time.time * framesPerSecond) % frames.Length;
    image.texture = frames[index];
}
```

I have one array for all images of all characters. How can I say, which 3 images I want to take from the array? Something like this:

```
void Update()
{
    switch(currentCharacterName)
    {
        case "character1":
            // take elements 0 1 2 from array 'frames'
            image.texture = frames[index];
            break;
        case "character2":
            // take elements 3 4 5 from array 'frames'
            image.texture = frames[index];
            break;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Can you store the images in a dictionary? Are the possible names stored in a list somewhere?

Comment: @MaorVeitsman Yes, I can do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly correctly.

```
string[] names = new[] {"name1", "name2", "name3"}; // sample array
void Update(){
    int index = names.indexOf(currentCharacterName);
    var framesByName = names.Skip(index * 3).Take(3).ToArray();
}
```

Alternatively, you can make it faster and more elegant if you change the names array into a dictionary in which every name has its respective index.

```
Dictionary<string, int> names = new {{"name1", 1}, {"name2", 2}, {"name3", 3}}; // Now you can directly access the index without using indexOf
```

But the most elegant solution would be to alter they way you save your frames:

```
public Dictionary<string, Texture[]> frames; // Here you can have pairs of character name and an array of its three textures..
```

With this you can simply access the required three elements directly.

Comment: Thanks! I'll do it

Comment: LINQ would probably be overkill for this particular application. Instead of generating a new array, you can reference the images in the original array by using the indices `index * 3`, `index * 3 + 1`, and `index * 3 + 2`.